# how to use mdx query in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, mdx, olap

I write one  mdx query for my olap cube .This query is doing abc analysis.But I want to use in excel for creating table and graphs.But I dont know how can I use this mdx query? I try in power bi ,it is working fine but in excel I didnt.please I need help.Thanks

My MDX Query :

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Measure for ABC] AS
[Measures].[Profit]
SET [Set for ABC] AS
NonEmpty( [Items].[Item Description].[Item Description].MEMBERS,
[Measures].[Measure for ABC] )
SET [A] AS
TopPercent( [Set for ABC], 30, [Measures].[Measure for ABC] )
SET [B] AS
TopPercent( [Set for ABC], 80, [Measures].[Measure for ABC] ) -
[A]
SET [C] AS
[Set for ABC] - [A] - [B]
MEMBER [Measures].[ABC Group] AS
iif( IsEmpty( [Measures].[Measure for ABC] ), null,
iif( Intersect( [A],
[Items].[Item Description].CurrentMember
).Count > 0,
'A',
iif( Intersect( [B],
[Items].[Item Description].CurrentMember
).Count > 0,
'B',
'C' ) ) )
SELECT
{ [Measures].[Measure for ABC],
[Measures].[ABC Group] } ON 0,
NON EMPTY
{ [Items].[Item Description].[Item Description].MEMBERS } ON 1
FROM
[PrxSaleCube]
```

[image]

Power BI:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Pivot -> Home -> Get External Data -> From Database -> From Analysis Services

Comment: Hi Danylo, I know how use olap cube in excel .But I want to write above mdx query in excel.I try it in excel but excel not accept my mdx query.For example excel not accept WİTH syntax and MEMBER

Comment: No way, what does it return? I've just created the following MDX query with no problem: with member measures.lol as 1 select measures.lol on 0 from [MyCube]

Comment: Danylo,I added one picture.you can look .I want to use this mdx query in excel.do you have any suggestion? I can use power bi .but I didnt use in excel

Comment: Excel screenshot where I put my MDX code: https://blogs.office.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Power-Query-for-Excel-September-2015-update-1.png

Comment: sorry I dont understand .I try with power bi.not excel.I dont know how to use this mdx query in excel

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with your Excel. See my answer above, please show your screen after "From Analysis Services" step. Why can't you simply insert your MDX code in Excel like you do it in PowerBI? (the use the same mechanism).

Comment: Thanks Danylo.I understand .I dont know power query for excel so I dont understand.But I search power query for excel I understand .Thanks too much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you start a PivotTable against Analysis Services by clicking Data tab... from Other Sources... From Analysis Services.

Then add your named sets using MDX as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-named-set-in-an-olap-pivottable-8148265e-f843-4300-98f5-37c74f96d770?&ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us&fromar=1#__toc265054241) and create your calculated measures as described [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2012/10/15/calculated-member-and-measures-in-excel-2013/?).

Then drag and drop the fields and measures and sets to build your Pivot.